# How to use endpoints that require authentication in Spring Boot server using JWT?

Tags: spring, authentication, server, jwt, http-status-code-403

I'm working on a project in which I need to develop three servers. One of them is called users and this is where I have the public endpoints to register and log in users. Then I have two other servers called plans and subscriptions. On my plans server the majority of the endpoints require authentication as Marketing Director, so, for example, to create a plan I first need to log in as a Marketing Director on my Users server and then provide the token as a Bearer token on /create endpoint. I'm developing the servers with Spring Boot and the authentication is done via JWT.

The issue is that I'm unable to access these endpoints that require authentication, giving me 403 forbidden error. The JWT seems correct and, in jwt.io website, gives me the corrected role
String like, although it says it has invalid signature:

```
{
  "iss": "example.io",
  "sub": "13,river@mail.com",
  "exp": 1698370908,
  "iat": 1698334908,
  "roles": "Marketing Director"
}
```

I have the same public and private key to generate the tokens on all servers and all the roles are defined on the users server.

I'll share the most relevant code:

**Security Configuration class on my Users server**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor

public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserRepository userRepo;

    @Value("${jwt.public.key}")
    private RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey;

    @Value("${jwt.private.key}")
    private RSAPrivateKey rsaPrivateKey;

    @Value("${springdoc.api-docs.path}")
    private String restApiDocPath;

    @Value("${springdoc.swagger-ui.path}")
    private String swaggerPath;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(username -> (UserDetails) userRepo.findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(format("User: %s, not found", username))));
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // Enable CORS and disable CSRF
        http = http.cors().and().csrf().disable();

        // Set session management to stateless
        http = http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and();

        // Set unauthorized requests exception handler
        http = http.exceptionHandling(
                exceptions -> exceptions.authenticationEntryPoint(new BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                        .accessDeniedHandler(new BearerTokenAccessDeniedHandler()));

        // Set permissions on endpoints
        http.authorizeRequests()
        // Swagger endpoints must be publicly accessible
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll().antMatchers(format("%s/**", restApiDocPath)).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(format("%s/**", swaggerPath)).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll();

    }
    // Used by JwtAuthenticationProvider to generate JWT tokens
    @Bean
    public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
        final JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(this.rsaPublicKey).privateKey(this.rsaPrivateKey).build();
        final JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwks = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwks);
    }

    // Set password encoding schema
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    // Used by spring security if CORS is enabled.
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

    // Exposing authentication manager bean
    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

**Users Controller Class**

```
@Tag(name = "Authentication")
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/user")
public class AuthApi {
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private final JwtEncoder jwtEncoder;

    private final UserDTOMapper mapper;

    private final UserService service;


    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> login(@RequestBody @Valid final AuthRequest request) {
        try {
            //"authenticationManager.authenticate" is invoking the authentication
            // mechanism configured in SecurityConfig class (authenticationManagerBean method)
            final Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getUsername(), request.getPassword()));

            final User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
            

            final Instant now = Instant.now();
            final long expiry = 36000L;

            final String scope = authentication.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                    .collect(joining(" "));

            final JwtClaimsSet claims = JwtClaimsSet.builder().issuer("example.io").issuedAt(now)
                    .expiresAt(now.plusSeconds(expiry)).subject(format("%s,%s", user.getId(), user.getUsername()))
                    .claim("roles", scope).build();

            final String token = this.jwtEncoder.encode(JwtEncoderParameters.from(claims)).getTokenValue();

            return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, token).body(mapper.toUserView(user));
        } catch (final BadCredentialsException ex) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
        }
    }
```

**AuthoryRole class on Users server**

```
@Value
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuthorityRole implements GrantedAuthority {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final String ADMIN = "Admin";
    public static final String MARKETING_DIRECTOR = "Marketing Director";
    public static final String CUSTOMER = "Customer";
    public static final String SUBSCRIBER = "Subscriber";

    private String authority;
}
```

**Security configuration on my plans server**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${jwt.public.key}")
    private RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey;

    @Value("${jwt.private.key}")
    private RSAPrivateKey rsaPrivateKey;

    @Value("${springdoc.api-docs.path}")
    private String restApiDocPath;

    @Value("${springdoc.swagger-ui.path}")
    private String swaggerPath;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // Enable CORS and disable CSRF
        http = http.cors().and().csrf().disable();

        // Set session management to stateless
        http = http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and();

        // Set unauthorized requests exception handler
        http = http.exceptionHandling(
                exceptions -> exceptions.authenticationEntryPoint(new BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                        .accessDeniedHandler(new BearerTokenAccessDeniedHandler()));

        // Set permissions on endpoints
        http.authorizeRequests()
        // Swagger endpoints must be publicly accessible
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll().antMatchers(format("%s/**", restApiDocPath)).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(format("%s/**", swaggerPath)).permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/api/plan").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/plan/**").hasRole("Marketing Director")

                //.anyRequest().authenticated()
                // Set up oauth2 resource server
                .and().httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults()).oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    }
    // Used by JwtAuthenticationProvider to generate JWT tokens
    @Bean
    public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
        final JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(this.rsaPublicKey).privateKey(this.rsaPrivateKey).build();
        final JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwks = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwks);
    }

    // Used by JwtAuthenticationProvider to decode and validate JWT tokens
    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(this.rsaPublicKey).build();
    }

    // Extract authorities from the roles claim
    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        final JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles");
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");

        final JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);
        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }

    // Used by spring security if CORS is enabled.
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

}
```

**Plans Controller Class**

```
@Tag(name = "Plans")
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/plan")
class PlanController {
    private final PlanService service;

    private final PlanDTOMapper planMapper;

    @Operation(summary = "Create a new plan")
    @PostMapping("/create")
    //@RolesAllowed("Marketing Director")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ResponseEntity<PlanDTO> create(@Valid @RequestBody final CreatePlanRequest resource) {

        final var plan = service.create(resource);

        final URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequestUri()
                .pathSegment(plan.getName())
                .build()
                .toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(planMapper.toPlanView(plan));
        //This entire statement combines the status code (201 Created) and the newly created resource's
        //URI along with its transformed representation (PlanDTO).
        //It creates a complete ResponseEntity indicating the successful creation of a resource.
    }
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JWTs to authorize requests between micro-services, you'd better use OAuth2. Properly.

This means identifying all of the OAuth2 actors:

- authorization server (what delivers tokens)
- client(s) (what gets tokens from authorization server to authorize requests sent to resource servers)
- resource sever(s) (what checks tokens validity and takes access decision)
- resource owners (users and services issuing request in their own name, without the context of a user)

You should also consider the latest recommendations to use only confidential clients (on the servers you trust), which requires to use sessions (and CSRF protections) between mobile apps or SPAs (Angular, React, Vue,...) and a backend for front-end (something like spring-cloud-gateway with `oauth2Login` and `TokenRelay` filter).

You might refer to [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#securing-spring-applications-with-oauth2) for more OAuth2 background and instructions to configure the different OAuth2 actors.